# Does Scott Meyers's advice to prefer non-member non-friend methods apply to object construction?

Tags: c++, constructor

Let's say I have a class:

```
class C{
  int x_;
  int y_;
public:
  C(int x, int y): x_(x), y_(y){}
};
```

Then I want to add construction from a string, which would just parse `x` and `y`. Before reading Meyers's book I would usually make it another constructor in class `C`. However, it's also possible to make it non-member non-friend:

```
C CFromString(const std::string& s){
  int x, y;
  //...parse them somehow, throw exception if needed...
  return C(x,y);
}
```

To me this is standard situation for many "value classes", when there is a "main" constructor which sets private members to provided values (probably checking there correctness). Other constructors for such classes are often just calculate these values from some other arguments.

Are there any drawbacks in making such constructors non-member non-friends like in my example?

**Upd.** I understand the Meyers's advice, and what are the advantages of NMNF functions. There is just no examples of NMNF object construction in his book, so I want to ensure that his advice applies to construction as well.

Comment: The NMNF function doesn't have access to the class's non-public members, so it can't break the class invariants easily, and the author of the NMNF probably won't get informed of internal refactorings of the class. She'll probably also ship the NMNF in a separate library which users would only include when they actually need it. Oh, wait, you said "drawbacks"?

Comment: If you make it a constructor, you can use a string as an argument to a function that expects a `C`, and it will be converted automatically. If it's a separate function, you have to call the function explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar Nope, that's not it. Non-member functions can be overloaded. You can make a generic `CFrom` non-member non-friend function, which is overloaded in multiple ways for different argument types.

Comment: @Kaz But you still have to call `CFrom()` explicitly, don't you? You can't have `void someFun(C)`, and then call `someFun(aString)`, you'd have to write `someFun(CFrom(aString))`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, because this construction doesn't count as a user-defined conversion (of which you can have one, implicitly, IIRC). Of course C++ isn't going to infer that the argument can be matched if we just take the string through this `CFrom` function, haha! So that is a disadvantage; make an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One drawback is a bit of inconsistency, which is an esthetic concern.

You're calling a `CFromString` constructor function rather than invoking a constructor called `C`. The relationship between them is arbitrary, just through the `C` prefix in the name.

If you make it a `static` member function, then you can call it `C::FromString` so that it belongs to the class.

If this is done all over the place in a large project, some sort of convention would help. Like say, whenever we have a class `C`, and a non-member constructor function for making `C`-s, let's always call it `CCons`, and then always use overloading for different types. Thus, if we have a `Widget` class, we then call our overloaded family `WidgetCons`:

```
Widget WidgetCons(const std::string &s) { /* make it from string */ }
Widget WidgetCons(int i) { /* make it from int */ }
```

and so on. If this is consistent in our 250,000 line codebase, whenever someone sees any `FooCons` or `BarCons`, they know exactly what it is.

Comment: The `C::FromString` defeats the non-member point of the idea: that function has access to internals of `C` objects. Otherwise I agree, some general convention is good to have.

Comment: @ConstantinBaranov  Excellent point; that aspect of it would be better expressed with namespaces, to stick to the non-friend, non-member principle.

Answer (score 5):

If you start adding constructors for every possible way a class can be serialized, you are tightly coupling that class with those serialization methods.

It is preferred that you separate the class and the serializer in order to separate concerns. Let the class focus on what the class does and the serializer on what it does (read json or whatever)

You have to consider that your class might be serialized from a file, from a socket, from json, from xml, from a database...from any number of things.

That's why in modern programming we use interfaces.
We also make use of the Factory pattern.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but my question is not about serializing - it was only an example, maybe misleading.

Comment: There is no general rule and when one uses a general rule, it's wrong.